# Many-to-Many Relationship Between Objects

Tags: c++, object, oop, many-to-many

Here is the code
In Movie.hpp

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define  MOVIE_H

class Movie
{
  private:
    std::string title;
  public:
    std::string getTitle() const {return this->title;}  // const added 
    void setTitle(std::string newTitle){this->title = newTitle;}
};


#endif
```

In Actor.hpp

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define  ACTOR_H

#include "Person.hpp"
#include "Movie.hpp"

class Actor: public Person
{
  private:
    std::vector<Movie> movieList;
  public:
    void addMovie(Movie newMovie){this->movieList.push_back(newMovie);}
    void printMovies()
    {
      for(Movie movie: this->movieList)
      {
        std::cout << movie.getTitle() << '\n';
      }
    }
};

#endif
```

In Main.cpp I'm doing something like

```
Movie movie1, movie2, movie3; 
  Actor actor1, actor2;

  movie1.setTitle("Transformers");
  movie2.setTitle("Interstellar");
  movie3.setTitle("The Matrix");

  actor1.setName("Brad");
  actor1.setAge(57);
  actor1.addMovie(movie1); //here
  actor1.addMovie(movie2);

  actor2.setName("Justin");
  actor2.setAge(30);
  actor2.addMovie(movie3);
```

I have been instructed that I'm not following many-to-many relationship. In other words, if actor1 and actor2 have a connection with the same movie, they should share the same 'Movie' object.
In my case, they have different movie objects.
The proper way is to store pointers to Movie inside Actor:

```
std::vector<Movie*> movieList;
```

(collection of pointers, not of objects)

and inside Movie:

```
std::vector<Actor*> actorList;
```

Another proper way, I prefer this one, is to add a separate class

```
class Role {
private:
   Actor* actor;
   Movie* movie;
};
```

and store collection of such objects inside Movie and Actor, here values (not pointers)  are OK

```
std::vector<Role> movieList; //inside Actor

std::vector<Role> actorList; //inside Movie
```

I have the idea how to solve above problem but I'm unable to make the changes in above code while using pointer. Can someone please help me out what changes will be there when I use pointers  ?

Comment: `std::vector<Movie>` will create a vector of `Movie` object *copies*. Each element in the vector will be a copy of some other `Movie` object. And the different `Movie` objects will be truly different, so modifications to one object will not propagate to the other copies. The simple solution to this is to use *pointers*. Just like you seem to be doing? So please [edit] your question to elaborate on the problems you have.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a plan for how to fix this. Are you facing any specific problems in your implementation of the `Role` idea?

Comment: @NathanPierson yes I got the instruction how to solve that problem but I'm unable to implement it. Can you please help me out what changes will be there if I use pointers ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got the idea how to solve the problem but I'm having issues on how to implement it. Can you show me the changes I have to make if I use pointers instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectors and smart pointers. I don't know which version of c++ you use, but you can use `std::shared_ptr<Movie>` and `std::shared_ptr<Actor>`. And each movie and actor will have his own vector of shared pointers.
Such smart pointers are available from c++ 11. So if you use version of c++  that is before c++ 11, you can use `boost` library, which include these smart pointers: `boost::shared_ptr<Movie>` and `boost::shared_ptr<Actor>`

Comment: sorry, java is on my screan now. Of course I mean c++ version. boost - is a library that allows to use in early versions of c++ language some tools, that are available in late versions of c++ (like c++11, or c++20). So the general idea of my post is to use vectors of pointers. Second thing: if you want to avoid memory leaks, you need to manage your Movie and Actor objects that you allocated. Either you do it manually, either you use smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have a master-list of movies and actors, each stored as a vector of  [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Then in the `Actor` and `Movie` objects you can have a vectors (also) of `std::shared_ptr` of each other.

So first the master lists:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>> master_movies;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>> master_actors;
```

And the classes:

```
// Forward declaration
class Movie;

class Actor
{
    // ...

public:
    void addMovie(std::shared_ptr<Movie> movie)
    {
        movies.emplace_back(movie);
    }

private:
    // Movies that the actor has been in
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>> movies;
};

class Movie
{
    // ...

public:
    void addActor(std::shared_ptr<Actor> actor)
    {
        actors.emplace_back(actor);
    }

private:
    // Actors in this movie
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>> actors;
};
```

Always create the actors and movies in the master lists, and add movies to actors from the movie master list, and add actors to movies from the actor master list:

```
auto fear = std::make_shared<Movie>();
fear->setTitle("Fear and loathing in Las Vegas");
master_movies.emplace_back(fear);

auto depp = std::make_shared<Actor>();
depp->setName("Johnny Depp");
master_actors.emplace_back(depp);

depp->addMovie(fear);
fear->addActor(depp);
```